# How to allow the user to build a schedule and execute some code (.net)?

Tags: .net, windows-server-2008-r2

I'm trying to build an application that will allow the user to setup N number of schedules, and then execute some different custom code for each schedule.

I know I could manually set this stuff up with Task Scheduler, and pass different arguments to a console application but I'd really like to allow the users to manage the schedules through a web UI.

There are lots of windows products that use similar complex schedule builders.  Is there any way I can tap into something like that, or any OSS projects that do something similar that I could harness?

The website and server(s) are all under my control and I was planning on writing the main processing component as a .net windows service if that matters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I came across these which I think might be pretty good for what I'm looking to do:

http://quartznet.sourceforge.net/

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/tsnewlib.aspx

Comment: I can vouch for Quartz, I've used it at a few companies and it works great and has lots of options.